# Card drop-down on react native

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to achieve a component drop on react native?

[image]

Something like this. Sorry for the paint skills. Thank you in advance .

Comment: Do you want to create your own component for this ?

Comment: Yes, that's the point. I know that there is for Text only, but that's not what I want. @GuruparanGiritharan

Comment: Did you try my answer ?

Comment: Yes I did, I had to change a few things but I liked the result, thank you.

Comment: Great, you are welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom component like below, You can change the render label to support the view you want.

This sample needs the data to be like the below object but you can create your own object.

```
const dataArray = [{value: 'Car', id: 1,},{value: 'Van',id: 2},{ value: 'Bus',id: 3}];

   //Usage
    <CustomDropDown data={dataArray} />

const CustomDropDown = (props) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(-1);

  const renderLabel = (item) => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          width: 200,
          height: 60,
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderRadius: 10,
          padding: 5,
          marginVertical: 3,
        }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>{item.value}</Text>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
          <Text>{item.value}</Text>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 15 }}>{item.value}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

  const renderItem = (item) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          setSelected(item.id);
          setOpen(!open);
          //Call back to external state
        }}>
        {renderLabel(item)}
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{}} onPress={() => setOpen(!open)}>
        {selected === -1 && <Text>Place holder text</Text>}
        {selected !== -1 &&
          renderLabel(props.data.find((x) => x.id === selected))}
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {open && (
        <View
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 70,
          }}>
          {props.data.map((item) => renderItem(item))}
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```